# Replacing Laravel blade files with Vue slowly over time but it's becoming messy

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

We have a Laravel app that has a nav bar on the main page that links to different areas on the site like this:

```
<li class="{{ activeLink(['admin/orders', 'admin/orders/open', 'admin/orders/fulfilled']) }}">
    <a href="/admin/orders/new">
</li>
```

and the route is mapped as follows: `Route::get('admin/orders/new', 'Admin\OrdersController@new');`

**OrdersController**

```
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    public function new() {
       return view('admin.orders');
    }
}
```

and this is where I removed the previous blade code and inject the Vue entry point:

**Orders.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

<div id="app-orders">
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm gradually replacing blade files with Vue, I am having to make 'new' Vue apps since there is no common entry point.  So right now I am looking to replace the Support page, which means I'll have to add an entry point on the `support.blade.php` like:

```
<div id="app-support">
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like to obviously replace the whole admin section and use Vue but the CTO wants to do it gradually so I'm wondering if this is the best approach or is there another way I can be doing this?

Comment: Why don't you wrap all your HTML in a single Vue instance? 
You wrap all your code in a <div id="vue-app"> .... </div>

Comment: ah, you mean wrap the whole HTML nav in an entry point and then i can either link to a blade for features we want to preserve or render Vue components for newly replaced ones?